# SKlearn import MLPClassifier fails

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am trying to use the [multilayer perceptron](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html#classification) from scikit-learn in python. My problem is, that the import is not working. All other modules from scikit-learn are working fine.

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
```

> Import Error: cannot import name MLPClassifier

I'm using the Python Environment Python64-bit 3.4 in Visual Studio 2015. 
I installed sklearn over the console with: `conda install scikit-learn`
I also installed numpy and pandas. After I had the error above I also installed [scikit-neuralnetwork](http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) with: `pip install scikit-neuralnetwork`
The installed scikit-learn version is 0.17.

What have I done wrong? Am I missing an installation?

----- EDIT ----

In addition to the answer of tttthomasssss, I found the solution on how to install the sknn library for neuronal networks. I followed this [tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html).
Do the following steps:

- `pip install scikit-neuralnetwork`
- download and install the [GCC compiler](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/)
- install mingw with `conda install mingw libpython`

You can use the [sknn](http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide_beginners.html#example-regression) library after.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`MLPClassifier` is not yet available in `scikit-learn` v0.17 (as of 1 Dec 2015). If you really want to use it you could clone `0.18dev` (however, I don't know how stable this branch currently is).

Comment: How can I clone the latest version?

Comment: @Noober See here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#retrieving-the-latest-code

Comment: I just went through this and the dev build is pretty stable with MLP.

Answer (score 6):

from shell/ terminal

```
conda update scikit-learn
```

Comment: you need to run conda update --all first

Answer (score 5):

I arrived here with the v0.17 problem too. I found a solution using pip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016238/sklearn-import-mlpclassifier-fails), namely

```
    pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
```

I had to execute `pip install cython` first though.

However, that installs `0.19.dev0` (currently), but `pip list` indicates that the latest is `0.18rc2`. Rather

```
    pip install scikit-learn==0.18.rc2
```

resolved the issue more satisfactorily.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get update; \
apt-get install -y python python-pip \
                    python-numpy \
                    python-scipy \
                    build-essential \
                    python-dev \
                    python-setuptools \
                    libatlas-dev \
                    libatlas3gf-base

update-alternatives --set libblas.so.3 /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3; update-alternatives --set liblapack.so.3 /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3

pip install -U scikit-learn
```

I have imported MLPClassifier from sklearn.neural_network and it does seem to work.

You could also handle this issues by using docker images. This allows any developer to recreate the environment in any server within a single minute. You can pull the image from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/acusensehub/scikit-opencv/~/dockerfile/)

This can also be performed very easily using the datmo-cli tool. We faced these problems ourselves and decided to build it.

You could also solve this with one click using Datmo
Disclaimer: I work at [Datmo](https://datmo.io/)