# How to fix: ImportError: cannot import name 'MLPClassifier'

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with this line of code:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
```

Every necessary package is installed such as numpy, scipy, sklearn. I also installed Anaconda. My operating system is windows 8, 64 version. I tried Python 2.7 and 3.5. None of these have helped. I also read somewhere that I may need a visual C++ compiler (version 10 for python 3.5). I found [this page](http://sebsauvage.net/python/mingw.html) but I can't figure out how to do the steps in this page. Isn't there any simpler and free way of doing this?

Comment: which version of sklearn?

Answer (score 1):

If your scikit-learn version is below 0.18dev (which it probably should be if you're using conda at this time), then your problem has already been answered in this question : [SKlearn import MLPClassifier fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016238/sklearn-import-mlpclassifier-fails)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much. To install this version, I downloaded the file on https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn 
I tried to run "python setup.py install". But I get this error: compiling C sources. error: Unable to find vcvarsal.bat.