# Fail to import MPLClassifier from SKlearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to run MPL Neural Network using the scikit-learn library running on Jupyter Notebook. However, I have been trying to import the MPLClassifier but failed. I also have tried solution from here, [SKlearn import MLPClassifier fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016238/sklearn-import-mlpclassifier-fails). I followed the steps and installed everything but could not import the module from SKlearn which are,

1. Installed the SKlearn using `pip install scikit-neuralnetwork`
2. Installed the mingw package using `conda install mingw libpython` and `conda install -c free mingw`, as the package is not available when using https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/
3. Checked its availability using `conda list`

It is giving the following error,
cannot import name 'MPLClassifier' from 'sklearn.neural_network'

May I get help on other alternatives to import the module?

Comment: Just to test, have you tried `dir(sklearn.neural_network)`, which should show: if it exists, and if the MLPClassifier exists. This should not fix the problem, but help others to get a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: Are you importing `MPLClassifier` or `MLPClassifier`?

Comment: it says that, name 'sklearn' is not defined. But i did import everything @Larry the Llama.

Comment: However, @Scratch'N'Purr noticed my problem, I did misspell the module. Thank you for the help.